# PHP loop to create an HTML table

Tags: php, loops

I have an array which is populated from a MySQL query:

```
if ($result) {
    $foundResult = true;
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        array_push($searchResultAccount,$row->Account);
        array_push($searchResultUsername,$row->Username);
        array_push($searchResultPassword,$row->Password);
        array_push($searchResultCreated,$row->Created);
        array_push($searchResultStrength,$row->Strength);
    }
} else {
    array_push($error,"No results found");
}
```

Further down in my page, I want to create a table and populate the bootstrap table with the results from the array. However, each cell in the table prints all sets of results for that given field. I suspect I have a problem with my loop logic. I tried changing from a foreach to a for loop but still no luck:

```
<tbody>
  <?php for ($x = 0; $x < sizeof($result); $x++) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($searchResultAccount); $i++){echo($searchResultAccount[$i]);}?></td>
      <td><?php for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($searchResultUsername); $i++){echo($searchResultUsername[$i]);}?></td>
      <td><?php for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($searchResultPassword); $i++){echo($searchResultPassword[$i]);}?></td>
      <td><?php for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($searchResultCreated); $i++){echo($searchResultCreated[$i]);}?></td>
      <td><p>ExpiresHere</p></td>
      <td><?php for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($searchResultStrength); $i++){echo($searchResultStrength[$i]);}?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

The outcome looks like below:

[image]

I have 2 results in the array, and as you can see they're printing together in each cell. Any ideas on where I've went wrong ?

Edit:  Full PHP code as from the query string below:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE User_ID = :userid AND Account = :account";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindValue(':userid',$userid);
    $stmt->bindValue(':account',$account);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);

    if($result) {
        $foundResult = true;
        foreach($result as $row) {
            array_push($searchResultAccount,$row->Account);
            array_push($searchResultUsername,$row->Username);
            array_push($searchResultPassword,$row->Password);
            array_push($searchResultCreated,$row->Created);
            array_push($searchResultStrength,$row->Strength);
        }
    } else {
        array_push($error,"No results found");
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the full PHP code starting from the query string?

Comment: Why not use `array_walk`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work like this:

```
foreach($result as $row) {
    ?>
        <tr>
           <td><?php echo $row->Account; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row->Username; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row->Password; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row->Created; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row->Strength; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
}
```

with this approach you create table row for each result row

Comment: Thank you so much.  Works perfect.  Really appreciate the help.  Will mark your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove your for loops inside of td elements

```
foreach($result as $row) {
        <tr>
           <td><?php echo $row->Account;?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row->Username;?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row->Password;?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row->Created;?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row->Strength;?></td>
        </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is occurring because of lines like this.

`for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($searchResultAccount); $i++){echo($searchResultAccount[$i]);}`

I'm "guessing" that the problem is occurring because this is the length of the rows you want to print, not the count of data you want the print on the table.

Try changing the rows from:

```
<?php for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($searchResultAccount); $i++){echo($searchResultAccount[$i]);}?>
```

into

```
<td><?php echo($searchResultAccount[$x]) ; } ?></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are now looping trough each result in each tablerow (tr). With this code, you are only focussing the result that belongs to the tr.

```
<tbody>
  <?php for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($result); $x++) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo($searchResultAccount[$x]);?></td>
      <td><?php echo($searchResultUsername[$x]);?></td>
      <td><?php echo($searchResultPassword[$x]);?></td>
      <td><?php echo($searchResultCreated[$x]);?></td>
      <td><p>ExpiresHere</p></td>
      <td><?php echo($searchResultStrength[$x]);?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the simplest way to repeat.